# How to Deserializes this XML document to generated C# class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have tried to read XML document and i have found a method of generating XSD file into a C# class.

XML Document :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<sdnList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd">
  <publshInformation>
    <Publish_Date>12/15/2011</Publish_Date>
    <Record_Count>5052</Record_Count>
  </publshInformation>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>11691</uid>
    <lastName>SERVICIOS DE CONTROL INTEGRAL DE OBRAS S.L. SIP SUCURSAL CARTAGENA</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
      <program>SDNT</program>
    </programList>
    <idList>
      <id>
        <uid>6028</uid>
        <idType>NIT #</idType>
        <idNumber>900106267-0</idNumber>
        <idCountry>Colombia</idCountry>
      </id>
    </idList>
    <addressList>
      <address>
        <uid>17543</uid>
        <address1>Carrera 3 No. 8-38</address1>
        <city>Cartagena</city>
        <country>Colombia</country>
      </address>
      <address>
        <uid>17544</uid>
        <address1>Carrera 4 No. 8-41</address1>
        <city>Cartagena</city>
        <country>Colombia</country>
      </address>
    </addressList>
  </sdnEntry>
  <sdnEntry>
    <uid>11692</uid>
    <lastName>INVERSIONES EL PROGRESO S.A.</lastName>
    <sdnType>Entity</sdnType>
    <programList>
      <program>SDNT</program>
    </programList>
    <idList>
      <id>
        <uid>6027</uid>
        <idType>NIT #</idType>
        <idNumber>806006517-7</idNumber>
        <idCountry>Colombia</idCountry>
      </id>
    </idList>
    <akaList>
      <aka>
        <uid>12373</uid>
        <type>a.k.a.</type>
        <category>weak</category>
        <lastName>I.P. S.A.</lastName>
      </aka>
    </akaList>
    <addressList>
      <address>
        <uid>17540</uid>
        <address1>Carrera 3 No. 8-38 Ofc. 1</address1>
        <city>Cartagena</city>
        <country>Colombia</country>
      </address>
      <address>
        <uid>17541</uid>
        <address1>Carrera 4 No. 8-41</address1>
        <city>Cartagena</city>
        <country>Colombia</country>
      </address>
      <address>
        <uid>17542</uid>
        <address1>Olaya Herrera Carrera 68 No. 32B-45</address1>
        <city>Cartagena</city>
        <country>Colombia</country>
      </address>
    </addressList>
  </sdnEntry>
```

Generated C# Class by `XSD tool`

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.5448
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.42.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class sdnList
{

    private sdnListPublshInformation publshInformationField;

    private sdnListSdnEntry[] sdnEntryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public sdnListPublshInformation publshInformation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.publshInformationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.publshInformationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("sdnEntry")]
    public sdnListSdnEntry[] sdnEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sdnEntryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sdnEntryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListPublshInformation
{

    private string publish_DateField;

    private int record_CountField;

    private bool record_CountFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Publish_Date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.publish_DateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.publish_DateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int Record_Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.record_CountField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.record_CountField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool Record_CountSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.record_CountFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.record_CountFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntry
{

    private int uidField;

    private string firstNameField;

    private string lastNameField;

    private string titleField;

    private string sdnTypeField;

    private string remarksField;

    private string[] programListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryID[] idListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryAka[] akaListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryAddress[] addressListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryNationality[] nationalityListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryCitizenship[] citizenshipListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryDateOfBirthItem[] dateOfBirthListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryPlaceOfBirthItem[] placeOfBirthListField;

    private sdnListSdnEntryVesselInfo vesselInfoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string firstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.firstNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.firstNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string lastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string sdnType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sdnTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sdnTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string remarks
    {
        get
        {
            return this.remarksField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.remarksField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("program", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] programList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.programListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.programListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("id", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryID[] idList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("aka", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryAka[] akaList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.akaListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.akaListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("address", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryAddress[] addressList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.addressListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.addressListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("nationality", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryNationality[] nationalityList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nationalityListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nationalityListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("citizenship", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryCitizenship[] citizenshipList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.citizenshipListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.citizenshipListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("dateOfBirthItem", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryDateOfBirthItem[] dateOfBirthList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateOfBirthListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dateOfBirthListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("placeOfBirthItem", IsNullable = false)]
    public sdnListSdnEntryPlaceOfBirthItem[] placeOfBirthList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.placeOfBirthListField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.placeOfBirthListField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public sdnListSdnEntryVesselInfo vesselInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vesselInfoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vesselInfoField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryID
{

    private int uidField;

    private string idTypeField;

    private string idNidCountryumberField;

    private string idCountryField;

    private string issueDateField;

    private string expirationDateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string idType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string idNidCountryumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idNidCountryumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idNidCountryumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string idCountry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idCountryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idCountryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string issueDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.issueDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.issueDateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string expirationDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.expirationDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.expirationDateField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryAka
{

    private int uidField;

    private string typeField;

    private string categoryField;

    private string lastNameField;

    private string firstNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string lastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string firstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.firstNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.firstNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryAddress
{

    private int uidField;

    private string address1Field;

    private string address2Field;

    private string address3Field;

    private string cityField;

    private string stateOrProvinceField;

    private string postalCodeField;

    private string countryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string address1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.address1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.address1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string address2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.address2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.address2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string address3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.address3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.address3Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string city
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cityField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string stateOrProvince
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stateOrProvinceField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stateOrProvinceField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string postalCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.postalCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.postalCodeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryNationality
{

    private int uidField;

    private string countryField;

    private bool mainEntryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool mainEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainEntryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mainEntryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryCitizenship
{

    private int uidField;

    private string countryField;

    private bool mainEntryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool mainEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainEntryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mainEntryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryDateOfBirthItem
{

    private int uidField;

    private string dateOfBirthField;

    private bool mainEntryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string dateOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dateOfBirthField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dateOfBirthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool mainEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainEntryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mainEntryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryPlaceOfBirthItem
{

    private int uidField;

    private string placeOfBirthField;

    private bool mainEntryField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int uid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uidField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uidField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string placeOfBirth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.placeOfBirthField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.placeOfBirthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool mainEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainEntryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mainEntryField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/sdnList.xsd")]
public partial class sdnListSdnEntryVesselInfo
{

    private string callSignField;

    private string vesselTypeField;

    private string vesselFlagField;

    private string vesselOwnerField;

    private int tonnageField;

    private bool tonnageFieldSpecified;

    private int grossRegisteredTonnageField;

    private bool grossRegisteredTonnageFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string callSign
    {
        get
        {
            return this.callSignField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.callSignField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vesselType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vesselTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vesselTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vesselFlag
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vesselFlagField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vesselFlagField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string vesselOwner
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vesselOwnerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vesselOwnerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int tonnage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tonnageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tonnageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool tonnageSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tonnageFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tonnageFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public int grossRegisteredTonnage
    {
        get
        {
            return this.grossRegisteredTonnageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.grossRegisteredTonnageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool grossRegisteredTonnageSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.grossRegisteredTonnageFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.grossRegisteredTonnageFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace Validus.New.Domain
{
    class Testdeserialize
    {
        public void test()
        {
            sdnList sdnEntry = null;
            string path = "D:/sdn1.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(sdnList));


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            sdnEntry = (sdnList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

**So how to deserialize this XML Document to C# class object ?**

Comment: What? In what way does it not work?  Be _specific_...

Comment: @JeffMercado : My code doesn't work . Thanks

Comment: If you mean that your code throws an exception, then the reader.Close() is probably guilty because .Deserialize will likely close it already. Otherwise that looks ok. Add the exception that you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you have any issues with serializer/deserializer, rather you got problem here:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); 
sdnEntry = (sdnList)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
reader.Close();
```

Try instead:

```
using(var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    sdnEntry = (sdnList)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
}
```